# How to send 2 images into 1 network in Tensorflow and calculate contrastive loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function

I currently need to do something quite similar to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6776

For example, I have a batch of images A, B, C ...., and I will generate an augmented batch for them as a, b, c .....

I will then send A (B or C) into an Inception network to get an output tensor "output_1", and I need to send a (b or c) into the same Inception network to get an output tensor "output_2", and I will use ||"output1- output2"|| as a contrastive loss.

At this moment, I am not sure how people usually handle such operations in Tensorflow. I searched online and did not find an answer (Although I guess it is related to "reuse" of network).

Here is what my source code looks like (I apologize because I can just paste a simplified version here):

```
class MyModel:
    ......
    def define_my_net(self):
        self.inputs_from_bloader = tf.placeholder(...)
        self.input = self.inputs_from_bloader
        self.output = slim.conv2d(self.input,...)
    ......
    def update(sess, inputs):
        feed_dict = utility.build_feed_dict(self.inputs_from_bloader, inputs)
        sess.run([my_op_list], feed_dict = feed_dict)
     ......

def train():
    data = importlib.import_module('some.datasets.reader')
    data = data.DataReader()
    model = importlib.import_module('MyModel')
    model.MyModel()
    model.define_my_net()      ### This is where network is defined
    batch = data.get_batch()    ### This is where A,B,C and a,b,c are generated.  
    model.update(sess, batch)    ### This is where training is done
```

I think I can output a batch like AaBbCc from "batch=data.get_batch" or change it to "batch1, batch2 = data.get_batch", but I don't know how to pass batch1 and batch2 into the defined network, because it may involve some architectural modification to the framework.

If you think the above source codes are too messy, any simpler examples will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate your network twice. These instantiations are usually called "towers". Both towers will use the same variables, but have different inputs and operations.

Depending on the high-level API you are using, you should look for some flag that controls variable `reuse` so that when you build your second tower, it does not create new variables. For example, search for `reuse` here https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variables.